# The Final Output is Different (In terms of world background) than the 3D EEVEE viewport blender 2.92.0

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I Setup the following scene in blender in the 3D EEVEE real time viewport
[image: EEVEE VIEWPORT]

The following output comes when I hit f12 or render the image (BOTH in CYCLES and EEVEE) then a weird grey background comes. What is the reason ?
[image: EEVEE RENDERED IMAGE]

Comment: please provide your blend file

Comment: https://github.com/dkdarshan760/BLENDER/blob/main/YETANOTHER%20INTRO.blend

Comment: I have used animation nodes by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, then make that cube.001 hide in render view too.

[image]

Comment: Actually, I want the background to be completely black, bcz of which I have set the world to complete black. I just want the render as it is seen in the realtime EEVEE viewport.

Comment: i updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

In your scene the object `Cube.001` is still being rendered. Since the cube has a white material the light casts shadows which cause the grey gradient.

There is a difference between temporarily hiding/unhiding in viewport (`H` and `Alt+H` on keyboard), permanently hiding ("disabling"), and hiding ("disabling") in renders. I assume you desired the last option and accidentally used the first.

[image: Annotated screenshot of the Outline editor,with some more filter controls enable.d]

In the Outline editor you can click on the funnel icon on the top right to enable more filter controls per object/collection. The third icon is the "Disable in Renders" function. When you enable this option for `Cube.001` the rendered image has a black background.